# Comparison operators not working?

Tags: php, comparison-operators

I have never stumbled upon this issue before. What is wrown with the following comparison:

```
$longest_side = 2.9;
if ($longest_side > 2.9) echo 'Too long'; // Returns true, incorrect
```

Some debugging:

```
var_dump($longest_side, 2.9) // Displays float(2.9) float(2.9)
```

The only way to make it work was to stringify the values

```
if ((string)$longest_side > (string)2.9) echo 'Too long'; // Returns false, OK
```

Is this a PHP bug or as constructed?

Comment: Read the [Wikipedia entry about floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)  and the [big red warning message in the PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) about comparing float values

Comment: And the correct way to make it work isn't to cast to string, but to compare using an epsilon, as describe in both the above linked pages

Comment: Thank you for a quick and helpful response.